# D3.js v4+ - How to determine specific location in force laypout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom, svg

The other tutorials/answers online are about D3.js v3.x or specific positions on draggable elements.

I looked at the documentation and I don't fully understand how to do it:

**I'm trying to prevent the red rectangles to overlap with the circles without changing the rectangles positions.**

I specified `fx` and `fy` and still no success.

```js
const nodes = d3.range(100).map(d => ({radius: 5, type: "circle"}));

const walls = [{}, {}, {}, {}].map((_, index) => ({
    fx: 200 * index,
    fy: 100,
    type: "wall"
}));

const circleCenters = [100, 300, 500];

d3.forceSimulation(nodes.concat(walls))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function (d, i) {
        if (d.type === "circle")
            return circleCenters[i % 3];
        else
            return d.fx;
    }))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(100))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => d.radius))
    .on('tick', ticked);

function ticked() {
    d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('rect')
        .data(walls)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('width', 100)
        .attr('height', 10)
        .attr('fill', 'red')
        .attr('x', d => d.x)
        .attr('y', d => d.y);

    const u = d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(nodes);

    u.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .merge(u)
        .attr('fill', 'blue')
        .attr('r', d => d.radius)
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="90vw" height="90vh">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fill the whole rect with guard nodes of the correct size.

If you want to see the guard circles un-comment part of the code.

There are 2 `g` elements, one containing the guard nodes and the other the `blue` nodes.

**Edit**

If you make the X-force a bit stronger the nodes get closer to the actual centers.

```
.force('x', d3.forceX()
    .x( (d, i) => (d.type === "circle") ? circleCenters[i % 3] : d.fx )
    .strength(0.3))
```

```js
const nodes = d3.range(100).map(d => ({radius: 5, type: "circle"}));

const walls = [{}, {}, {}, {}].map((_, index) => ({
    fx: 200 * index,
    fy: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 10,
    radius: 5,
    type: "wall"
}));

const circleCenters = [100, 300, 500];

// construct "invisible" circles covering the rects
var invCircles = [];
walls.forEach(e => {
    d3.range(e.fx+3, e.fx+e.width-3, 3).forEach(cx => {
        invCircles.push({
            fx: cx,
            fy: e.fy + e.radius,
            radius: e.radius,
            type: e.type
        });
    });
});

d3.forceSimulation(nodes.concat(invCircles))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(10))
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x( (d, i) => (d.type === "circle") ? circleCenters[i % 3] : d.fx ).strength(0.3))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(100))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => d.radius))
    .on('tick', ticked);

var wallGeom = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('class', 'wall');
var circlesGeom = d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('class', 'circles');

wallGeom.selectAll('rect')
    .data(walls)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', d => d.width )
    .attr('height', d => d.height )
    .attr('fill', 'red')
    .attr('x', d => d.fx)
    .attr('y', d => d.fy);

// wallGeom.selectAll('circle')
//     .data(invCircles)
//     .enter()
//     .append('circle')
//       .attr('fill', 'yellow')
//       .attr('r', d => d.radius)
//       .attr('cx', d => d.fx)
//       .attr('cy', d => d.fy);

function ticked() {

    const u = d3.select('svg')
        .select('.circles')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(nodes);

    u.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('fill', 'blue')
        .attr('r', d => d.radius)
      .merge(u)
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.js"></script>
<svg width="90vw" height="90vh"></svg>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. This is a great solution! Secondly, are you sure there is no solution that does not involve the creation of so many invisible circles? I may need to create 3000+ invisible balls. Isn't it too much for the browser? (My rects are wider and higher)

Comment: @StavAlfi Currently the force engine has no method to constrain the nodes. You have to do it yourself in the `tick()` method or create large and small (corners) invisible circles to fill the rects, The invisible nodes only involve the force engine and may slow it down but using the collision detection in `ticks()` is also not for free, and using circles is pretty fast.